# Android Wear: Timer like notification card on wear device

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm working on implementation of Pomodoro app for Android Wear.

I want to make [similar to standard timer UI/UX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1sgA.png), I guess it's implemented using displaying/updating notification with timer as title, so I'm showing notification and updating it periodically from Service:

```
private void updateNotification() {
    Intent stopActionIntent = new Intent(this, PomodoroActivity.class);
    stopActionIntent.setAction(PomodoroActivity.ACTION_STOP);
    PendingIntent stopActionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, stopActionIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Action stopAction = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
            R.drawable.ic_stop,
            getString(R.string.stop_pomodoro),
            stopActionPendingIntent)
            .build();

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bg_pomodoro_timer))
            .setContentTitle(convertDiffToTimer(System.currentTimeMillis(), timerDeadlineMs))
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().addAction(stopAction))
            .build();

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}
```

Unpleasure problem with such solution is blinking of notificaiton.

Any ideas how escape blinking? Or maybe other way to achieve target behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

To update ongoing/existing notification -

1. Use Same `Id` of Notification in Builder
2. Use `.setOnlyAlertOnce(true)`

`NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;
public void generateNotificationForTimer(String timeInString, boolean isFirstTime) {
    if (isFirstTime) {
        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle())
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setContentTitle("Timer Notification Demo")
                .setContentText("Time - " + timeInString)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_signin_btn_icon_dark);
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(110, notificationBuilder.build());
    } else {
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(timeInString);
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(110, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}`

Comment: It is working, I have tested my code with Emulator as well as on LG Wear. Check this demo project - [Sample Project on GitHub](https://github.com/vintesh/android-wear-samples)

Comment: Also still blinking on my side (LG G Watch).

Comment: I had the same issue on my Samsung Gear Live. What I did is to remove the app icon on the notification card to hide the blinking effect with `setHintHideIcon(true)`

Comment: @nicolas & others - I don't know if you have tried my GITHUB project or not. I double checked that, it is working fine for me. Can you share your code snippet or project link so that i can resolve issue?

Comment: It seems that it is because you use the BigPicture style for your notification that does not show the app icon. I guess that's why you do not see the notification blinking...

Comment: The solution seems to use `setUsesChronometer` and `setWhen` properties instead of directly updating the time. An example that works here https://github.com/AlexKorovyansky/WearPomodoro