# Android Wear notification prevent blinking icon when updating

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-notification

I can't seem to be able to create an Android Wear notification that updates with out blinking the app icon whereas the same code works fine on an Android phone.

Most referenced solutions talk about updating the same notification, use *setAlertOnlyOnce*, keeping the *ID* or *when* the same. However, whatever I do, every time the notification is updated it blinks (most noted by the App Icon).

As suggested here [Android Wear: Timer like notification card on wear device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499834/android-wear-timer-like-notification-card-on-wear-device) you can use *setHintHideIcon(true)* to hide the app icon, which hides the blinking part, however in the limited world of Android Wear Notifications the app icon plays a large part in the branding of the application.

If you want a timer, you can use *.setUsesChronometer(true)* and let the system update the timer which works perfectly. Unfortunately if you want to update something else than time (like steps or messages received count) it seems to me you're out of luck.

Below you can find code that works fine when run as a phone app, but blinks when run as a wearable app.

Commented line below to demonstrate that the notification still blinks (when running on wear, not the phone) that the notification still blinks when posting an unchanged notification on the wearable. Uncomment to update the notification again.

```
mNotification = buildNotification(WearMainActivity.this);
```

Therefore my question is if anyone has any further idea's we can explore to keep the notification from blinking or if we can write this down as an Android Wear bug?

```
public class WearMainActivity extends Activity {

    public final int NOTIFICATION_ID= 1;
    public Notification mNotification;
    public int count;
    public long when;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        count = 0;
        when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        mNotification = buildNotification(WearMainActivity.this);
        postDelayedHandler();
        finish();
    }

    private void postDelayedHandler(){

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                count++;
                mNotification = buildNotification(WearMainActivity.this);
                NotificationManager notifyMgr = ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE));
                notifyMgr.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
                postDelayedHandler();
            }
        }, 1000L);
    }

    private Notification buildNotification(Context context){
        return new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText("Count: "+count)
                .setWhen(when)
//                .setOngoing(true) //Don't do this, adds "Mute app" action
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .extend(new Notification.WearableExtender()
//                        .setHintHideIcon(true) //Hides the icon, so kinda hides the blink
                )
                .build();
    }
}
```

Tested on:
Wearable: Moto 360 (4.4W2) Wear Emulator (5.0.1)
Phones: Galaxy Nexus (4.3) and Nexus 5 (5.0.0)

Occurs: When running as a Wearable app or as phone notification displayed on Wearable. Works perfect on phone.

Referenced questions:
[How can I avoid blinking notification update while changing button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025056/how-can-i-avoid-blinking-notification-update-while-changing-button)
[Updating an ongoing notification quietly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406730/updating-an-ongoing-notification-quietly)
[How to properly update a notification post api 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512986/how-to-properly-update-a-notification-post-api-11)

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't quite understand -- does this also happen with regular notifications in phone apps (no wear component) that are automatically mirrored to the watch? Because I tested this scenario with your code and saw no flickering (Moto 360 with Android 5.0).

Comment: Ah thanks for noticing that. Apparently when you update a notification on your phone the system is smart enough not to send an unchanged notification to the Wearable.

To clarify I've made a video of the behaviour: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8QBuUjb_vTA

Comment: Update: This doesnt seem to happen on a Gear Live running 5.0. So two options: a) It doesnt flicker there due to its better hardware b) It might fixed in 5.0. Now waiting for my watch to receive the update to confirm either a or b... (Oh i wish I could just sideload the OTA ;) )

Comment: I would bet on (b). We shall see :)

Comment: So I just got the 5.0 update (took em long enough!) and the answer is: yes and no!

When you get an extended notification from an app that's started on the phone it works seamless without any blinking.
However, if you start an app from the watch it will still blink.

So now we have two different behaviours based on where the notification originated...

Comment: Oh wow... that is unfortunate :(

Comment: Just wanted to mention that i see flickering as well when creating/updating a notification on wear. Sony Smartwatch 3 on 5.0.1. I have opened an issue for that at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=121146

Comment: Thanks! I've starred the issue, I hope it helps.
As an update on what I've explored afterwards; I've looked into creating a Custom Notification using a Chronometer to update the text, as that's being used in the timer. However, it seems we can't "abuse" the Chronometer for anything other then time :(
So I'm still where we were before.

Comment: I think the current solution could be to create a DisplayView as the notification and completely style the card yourself.

Comment: Any news on this? I've starred the issue too. I would go the custom notification layout but can't get that to work either!

Comment: Can you test this out on the Android Wear 5.1 firmware that is rolling out now? If it is still a problem, then I will see if I can get this fixed.

Comment: That would be great, thanks! Will do once I get the update on my Moto 360 (last time it took 2-3 weeks). Otherwise I can DM you an APK on G+?

Comment: It might have something to do with you returning a new builder each time you call buildNotification.  If you use a new builder each time, then I am guessing Android has to rebuild the view all over again causing it to briefly disappear.  Look at this question and answer for help.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15538209/2388208
If it works, let me know and I will post in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
NotificationManager notifyMgr = 
    ((NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE));
```

With:

```
NotificationManagerCompat notifyMgr =
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
```

[More information](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html)

You also making a lot of updates. Every update is send via bluetooth to Wear. You should create self-install app to Android Wear. The delay of sending is about 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem a while back when I was working with Android Wear but the code in unfortunately gone. Anyway, what I did was to not BUILD the notification every time I wanted to update it, I just tagged the notification the first time I created it and then I retrieved it with the `TAG` and made my changes directly to that object. That completely stopped the flickering...